# Coral Micro camera stream: A new window does not appear OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

Tags: stream, camera, google-coral

this applies to the Google Coral Micro only:
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/get-started

create and install udev rules as per arduino:
https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board-micro/arduino/#3-try-the-face-detection-example

for Ubuntu only, possibly:
sudo apt-get install python-tk

after a few unplugs etc... started working of its own accord....

The first page of instructions for starting Coral Micro states:
"A new window should appear" however using Ubuntu 22.04 no window or camera stream occurs.
using screen: data is as expected.

OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host

How to fix?

```
python3 apps/multicore_model_cascade/multicore_model_cascade.py
Client connecting to 10.10.10.1:27000... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jonathan/coralmicro/apps/multicore_model_cascade/multicore_model_cascade.py", line 398, in <module>
main()
File "/home/jonathan/coralmicro/apps/multicore_model_cascade/multicore_model_cascade.py", line 385, in main
with SocketClient(args.host, args.port) as sock:
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "/home/jonathan/coralmicro/apps/multicore_model_cascade/multicore_model_cascade.py", line 362, in SocketClient
sock.connect((host, port))
OSError: [Errno 113] No route to host
```